# Security Guarantees, Pitfalls of Proposed Method

Tags: encryption, cryptography, signature

I want to send messages from Alice to Bob via a transport method akin to UDP, so non-connected.  I'll assume Eve the eavesdropper can obtain a copy of what is sent and that Mallory the attacker can do all that Eve can AND send to Bob. I'll assume also that Mallory cannot man-in-the-middle, i.e. cannot stop a message from Alice to Bob from reaching Bob, but Mallory CAN alter data and CAN just replay intercepted messages. My bandwidth is limited, so I don't want too much data added to 'user data' to achieve the data protection.

I want to achieve data confidentiality (encryption) plus tamper-proof (integrity) and authenticity guarantees, basically to reduce Mallory's capabilities to nil.  I propose this:

Alice and Bob share a secret key, for purposes of encryption (e.g. AES).

Alice and Bob share a secret key, for purposes of signing/verification (e.g. HMAC+SHA256).

The encryption and signature keys may be same or distinct.

A nonce shall be included in messages Alice sends to Bob.  A UUID could serve as a nonce, giving me a 16 byte nonce.  Advancing time could also serve as nonce.

For plaintext data P, Alice encrypts this to produce C, then appends a nonce N to produce C+N.  She then signs C+N, obtaining S, and appends S to C+N, producing C+N+S. This is what gets sent to Bob.  Eve/Mallory can't derive P, nor can Mallory alter a message, nor replay it, nor author new messages.

Bob has to manage a 'nonce store' of all nonces he has ever seen.  Or perhaps use time as the nonce (reducing the store to a single value), but then onus is on Alice to produce monotonically increasing values.

Given that most cryptographic protocols (e.g. TLS) work over a connected model, e.g. TCP, I haven't been able to find any off-the-shelf (accepted!) 
methods, hence this proposal.

Any help appreciated, especially of the 'you don't want to do it like that because it will suffer security holes X, Y, Z' variety.  I am aware of the whole 'encrypt then sign' debate, and don't really want to bring that into this.

UPDATE: In response to replies suggesting DTLS and use of time for nonces, I'll have to elaborate on aspects on my non-connected model that I hoped were't relevant in the initial post but obviously are.  In my model, Alice doesn't actually send directly to Bob.  The messages are held by an intermediary, think of it as a mail server.  And Bob may not check his 'Inbox' for hours or even days from the moment Alice has posted a message. Further, Bob and Alice's clocks are not synchronized, so having an 'expiry time' x is not trivial

Comment: Why don't you use DTLS?

Comment: Crypt design questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method is pretty sound already.  I would advise, however:

- Don't use the same key for encrypting as you do for the MAC.  There aren't any known theory-based interactions between AES and HMAC, but practical reasons (key leakage etc.) mean that having two different keys is likely better.
- You say you don't want to get into it, but there are very few reasons not to encrypt-then-mac.  You should prefer this if possible.
- Storing all nonces forever is fairly tedious.  Use a time-based signature expiry approach:

  - Alice encrypts `C = E(M)` and appends the current time, `T`, then signs to produce `S`.  She sends `C + T + S` to Bob.
  - Bob checks if T is within `x` seconds of the current time.  If it is not, Bob ignores the message.
  - Bob checks if he recognizes `S`.  If he does, Bob ignores the message.
  - Bob stores `S` temporarily for `x` seconds, after which he forgets it.
  - Bob decrypts `M = D(C)` and processes `M`.

The value of `x` here can theoretically be anything you like, but I'd suggest something in the range of 5-10 seconds or so.

Comment: I'm not understanding your points about Bob recognizing S and storing S. Isn't S just to guarantee integrity and identity (of Alice)? Are you proposing using S in the uniqueness assertion? Can you elaborate?

Comment: A duplicate message within the `x` seconds will be processed unless we have some way of recognizing it.  If it is a duplicate message (replay attack), then the signature will also be the same.  Thus, if we keep track of signatures for `x` seconds, we can identify messages that are replay attacks or accidental duplicates and safely ignore them.  Outside those `x` seconds, the message will be ignored anyway because of the time difference and the signature won't need to be remembered.